# Figuring when CountDownTimer is finished?

Tags: android, timer, countdowntimer

I have a question regarding Android's CountDownTimer. I was playing around with some of the methods like onStart and onFinish and I noticed that they're void functions. What I have in my code is that my timer starts when a function is called, but I want a condition for that if the timer is not finished, (ie it doesn't reach the amount of seconds I put for the timer's time) then simply cancel the timer. Is there a way to make countDownTimer's onFinish method a boolean as opposed to a void function? If anyone has any suggestions, that would be appreciated!